# Can't detect USB on RHEL9 VMware

Tags: linux, vmware, redhat-enterprise-linux, vmware-workstation, hardware-detection

I can't detect my USB on RedHat Enterprise 9, I did make sure that the removable disk is connected to VMware and not the host.
I can detect it on Kali Linux btw I even tried to use an external hard drive and still having the same issue.

[image]

Comment: Did you install VMware Tools in the Red Hat guest machine?

Comment: @John yes i did

Comment: I don't for sure.   I have VMware Workstation Pro on a Windows 11 Pro Host. My Ubuntu and Kali guests and my Windows Guests work with USB Passthrough.  Shot in the dark:  Spin up a Red Hat test machine and see if that works with USB passthrough.